# How can I handle camera and gallery output simultaneously, without using 2 times onActivityResult?

Tags: android, camera

I have a dialogue, which asks you to choose if to take a picture or to upload one from gallery. The taken/chosen image I set as background on a Button. how can I handle both outputs, as I can't use 2 times onActivityResult?
Here is the method that invokes the camera:

```
private void invokeCamera() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

And the method that lets you choose from a gallery:

```
private void openGallery() {

    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
}
```

I handle the image received from the camera on the following way:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && data != null) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            if (photo != null) {
                findViewById(), and whose background you want to update
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
                        imageUploader5.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), photo));
                    }
                } else {

                        imageUploader5.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), photo));
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As far as i understand your question, you want to process the bitmap coming from either of the source in a single callback method. Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is controlled from the dialog -> if I press "Take a photo", I want to process the photo taken. If is pressed "Upload from gallery", I want to process that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make a global variable

```
private final static int GET_PHOTO_BITMAP = 1234;
```

Then do the following

```
private void invokeCamera() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, GET_PHOTO_BITMAP);
}

private void openGallery() {

    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GET_PHOTO_BITMAP);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == GET_PHOTO_BITMAP && data != null) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            if (photo != null) {
                findViewById(), and whose background you want to update
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
                        imageUploader5.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), photo));
                    }
                } else {

                        imageUploader5.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), photo));
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here the key part is request code which is the second parameter of the `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)`

you can have different `requestCodes` for different operations and handle it this way in

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
switch(requestCode) {
     case code1:
        //task1
        break;
     case code2:
       //task2
       break;
       //and so on
     }
}
```

but since your case both the callbakcs for `startActivityForResult()` are supposed to perform the same operation, you can pass same code for both the calls as I have done in the above solution. But make sure that you pass same code when the operations done in the callback are similar.